# 'undefined reference' for only ONE function in entire shared library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I'm compiling a CPython Extension for an in-house library, and I'm pretty sure one of the functions that I'm using from the library is cursed.

When I run `ld` on the CPython Extension .so, it prints

```
./pyextension.so: undefined reference to `le_sig_cursed'
```

I don't believe it's an issue with the ordering of `-l` flags or it not finding the shared lib somehow, as the shared library contains hundreds of functions and **they all work fine except this one.**

Running `nm --extern-only | grep le_sig_cursed` on the shared lib shows that it does indeed exist.

```
0002ff70 T le_sig_cursed
```

Running that on the extension shows undefined (as expected).

```
U le_sig_cursed
```

Its prototype in the shared library's header looks like this

```
void le_sig_cursed(void);
```

There are other functions in the same header file with the exact same signature yet they link fine.

I'm using `--no-undefined`, and it doesn't complain at link time. Only when I run it or pass the extension into `ld` does it fail to resolve this one function.

I could understand if the library failed to load and none of the functions worked, but this one doesn't seem to have anything special about it yet it's the only one that fails. How do I diagnose this?

Comment: Try to check your symbol is exported with the C style or C++ style. If C style please use extern "C" to modify your symbol.

Comment: Please post the output of `objdump -t <the_in_house_shared_library> | grep le_sig_cursed`

Comment: @MikeKinghan `0002ff70 g     F .text  00000024              le_sig_cursed`